# How do I use a FreeRV as a theano function input in pymc3

Tags: theano, pymc

I am trying to use `pymc3` to model my system: `n` stochastic variables, of unknown distribution, which are related to some observed data `z` by the function `findz`. I have written the function `findz` using theano, however I am not sure how to input the stochastics into my theano code. This is what I have tried:

```
w = T.dscalar('w')
I = T.dvector('i')
R = T.dvector('r')
L = I.size-1
Cn = np.array([1,-1])*T.sqrt(w/R[-1])))

result, updates = theano.scan(fn=step, \
    sequences=[dict(input=I[::-1],taps=[-1,0]),R[::-1]], n_steps=L,\
    outputs_info=Cn, non_sequences = w)

final_result = result[-1]
find_z = theano.function(inputs=[I,R,w],outputs=final_result,updates=updates)

interfaces = np.logspace(2,3.9,9)[3:]

with pm.Model() as model:
    list_of_dist = [pm.Uniform('res'+str(i),1,100,testval=50) for i in range(len(interfaces))]
    z_hat = pm.Deterministic('z_hat',find_z(interfaces,list_of_dist,10))
    z_like = pm.Normal('z_like',mu=z_hat,sd=z_err,observed=z)
```

This returns an error at the z_hat line:

> ValueError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   "scan_pm_v.py:60"  at index 1(0-based)', 'setting an array element
>   with a sequence.')

I can set the `list_of_dist` to be a numpy object, which then gives the error

> AttributeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   "scan_pm_v.py:60"  at index 1(0-based)', "'float' object has no
>   attribute 'dtype'")

at the same line. I've also tried making the input a theano tensor by adding the line:

```
list_of_dist = T.stacklists(list_of_dist)
```

Which then returns the error:

> TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   "scan_pm_v.py:60"  at index 1(0-based)', 'Expected an array-like
>   object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function
>   on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')

Comment: I am having the same error with other libraries using theano. can't figure out why...